# Axios Request Interceptors - Header Value not Updating as per State Value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I'm currently making an API call to a public API that returns a random fact about Cats. I also added the Axios interceptors to append a new Request header inside an **UseEffect** and was expecting the **X_TESTING_HEADER** to be updated each time the **updateHeader** state value was changed.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    axios.interceptors.request.use(config => {
    config.headers.X_TESTING_HEADER = `${updateHeader}`;
    return config;
   });
  }, [updateHeader]);
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/axios-interceptors-issues?file=src/Shell.js has the working example with all the necessary code blocks. Please check https://axios-interceptors-issues.stackblitz.io/ which runs the stackblitz code and open the N/W tab to check the Header values.

By default **updateHeader** value has been set as **false**, when a user lands on the Page, the **X_TESTING_HEADER** value is set as false. The below screenshot shows 2 Buttons named "Update Header" and "Get New fact".

[image]

on Click of the **Update Header**, toggling the state value between false and true, post clicking on the Update Header Button, it can be observed that the state Value on Screen is updated. when trying to Fetch a new Fact using the **Get New Fact** button, the ** X_TESTING_HEADER** value is still shown as false. How can I update the request headers based on state values, is the header only set once and a refresh is needed to update the header value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The example you gave with the interceptor creation inside the useEffect; will add a new interceptor every time the useEffect is called. So if you want to update an interceptor, you will first have to clean up any previously made interceptors on that request. https://axios-http.com/docs/interceptors

Interceptors are more for logic that doesn't change much. If you need to frequently set a new header, rather create a custom axios instance, one possible solution:

(see https://axios-http.com/docs/instance and https://axios-http.com/docs/config_defaults)

```
  const axiosInstance = axios.create({
    baseURL: END_POINT,
    headers: {X_TESTING_HEADER: `${updateHeader}`}
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    axiosInstance.defaults.headers.X_TESTING_HEADER = `${updateHeader}`;
  }, [updateHeader]);

  const getFacts = () => {
    axiosInstance
      .get(`${RANDOM_FACTS}`)
      .then(res => {
        setFacts(res.data.text);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  };
```

Comment: Thanks @StephanC, We had a similar situation where we'd set a header when starting the server, but then updating it as and when required on each individual GET/POST through the interceptor.

The header never updated though, seemed to stick with the previous interceptor added on the server starting.

Solution was to pass in the header directly into the GET/POST as config.